# How do I explicitly state that a value passed into an argument is a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I need to be able to use a value I create to be addressed as an existing data frame.

Example of what works out of a loop (I may have 10, 20... 100 data frames, so I would like to do this in a loop.

```
temp1.obj <- subset(temp1.obj, subset = nFeature_RNA > 200 & nFeature_RNA < 2500 & percent.mt < .2)
temp2.obj <- subset(temp2.obj, subset = nFeature_RNA > 200 & nFeature_RNA < 2500 & percent.mt < .2)
temp3.obj <- subset(temp3.obj, subset = nFeature_RNA > 200 & nFeature_RNA < 2500 & percent.mt < .2)
```

I do not know how to make the value in the paste argument call the associated data frame name.

```
for(i in 1:aggr_count) {
paste("temp",[i],".obj" sep="") <- subset("temp",[i],".obj" sep=""), subset = nFeature_RNA > 200 & nFeature_RNA < 2500 & percent.mt < .2)
}
```

Is there any command that can modify/state the value is that of an existing data frame?
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use lapply, not a for loop. Write a function and pass your data frames as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wish to use a loop, here is one way to do it:

```r
dfs <- list(df1, df2, ...)
for(i in length(dfs)) {
    dfs[[i]] <- subset(dfs[[i]], subset = ...)
}
```

The part it seemed you were missing was the `df[[i]]` part (eg how to reference a dataframe and overwrite it).

However, as Limey stated, this is basically what `lapply` does (list apply), and `lapply` is probably more efficient and more concise.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mget` to return all the objects into the global env and then use `lapply` to loop over

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^temp\\d+\\.obj$')), subset,
   subset = nFeature_RNA > 200 & nFeature_RNA < 2500 & percent.mt < .2)
```

If we need to update the objects in global env, use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```